# Single instance of Usercontrol used in multiple UserControls

Tags: wpf, prism

I am working on Prism WPF application. 
The scenario is I have a view (with filters say ViewF) and 2 other views which will be containing the ViewF. Something like below in XAML:

```
<UserControl View1>
    <local:ViewF/>
</UserControl>`

<UserControl View2>
    <local:ViewF/>
</UserControl>
```

The issue is I want to use the same instance and state of ViewF in View1 and view2. I tried passing the ViewF's datacontext to View1 and View2 but this is not working because xaml itself is creating different instances.

Any Idea please share how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have the same instance of `UserControl` in different parents. XAML will produce you an exception like `The instance of UserControl is already added as child to another container`. Why do you need "the same instance" of `UserControl`? It's impossible. You should somehow share this functionality through `DataContext`.

Comment: Fighting with almost same thing. Your comment puts my thought on right track. I was forgetting basic concept of MVC and similar ones. Share data not view.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem right, this would help you.

Lets assume, each view have a ViewModel. Lets say View1VM, View2VM and ViewFVM are the VMs for View1, View2 and ViewFM respectively. Let MainVM be the ViewModel of the window which will host View1 and View2.

Have a instance of ViewFVM in MainVM. While creating the instances of View1VM and View2VM, inject the instance of MainVM(can also use interfaces so that only relevant data is exposed to each View) and have a property in both View1 and View2 which returns the instance of ViewFVM of mainVM. Bind this to the datacontext of ViewF in xaml.

Code would be like,

```
public class ViewFVM
{
    //Store the state of ViewF
}

public class MainVM
{
    public ViewFVM viewFVM;
    public MainVM()
    {
        View1VM view1VM = new View1VM(this);
        View2VM view2VM = new View2VM(this);
    } 
}

public class View1VM
{
     private MainVM _mainVM;
     public View1VM(MainVM mainVM)
     {
         _mainVM = mainVM;
     }

     public ViewFVM ViewFViewModel {get {return _mainVM.viewFVM;}}
}

public class View2VM
{
    private MainVM _mainVM;
     public View2VM(MainVM mainVM)
     {
         _mainVM = mainVM;
     }

     public ViewFVM ViewFViewModel {get {return _mainVM.viewFVM;}}
}
```

In xaml of each Views, ie for View1 and View2, set ViewFViewModel as datacontext through binding.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly define the filters as a shared [resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx), e.g.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:ViewF x:Key="filters"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
<UserControl> <!-- View1 -->
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="filters"/>
</UserControl>
<UserControl> <!-- View2 -->
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="filters"/>
</UserControl>
```